# Add property depending on condition json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm having some issues with my json schema. I need to add the property `amount` to the properties object only if the `transferType` is `ach`.
This is what I have right now:

```json
{
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "if": {
    "properties": { "transferType": { "const": "ach" } }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "amount": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "required": ["amount", "transferMethodId"]
  },
  "properties": {
    "blockchainAddress": { "type": "string" },
    "callbackUrl": { "format": "uri", "type": "string" },
    "currency": { "type": "string" },
    "transferMethodId": { "format": "uuid", "type": "string" },
    "transferType": {
      "enum": [
        "ach",
        "internationalWire",
        "scUsdc",
        "wire"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "blockchainAddress",
    "currency",
    "transferType"
  ]
}
```

Examples:

```json
{
   amount: '10',
   blockchainAddress: 'foo',
   currency: 'biz',
   transferType: 'ach'
}
```

This should be ok.

```json
{
   amount: '10',
   blockchainAddress: 'foo',
   currency: 'biz',
   transferType: 'wire'
}
```

This should return a validation error.

```
 "ajv": "^6.10.2",
    "validator.js": "^2.0.3",
    "validator.js-asserts": "^3.1.0"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The value of `properties` must be an object. You should be getting linting errors because `properties: { amount }` is not a valid object. Additionally, `additionalProperties` can only see properties defined in the same schema object. Schema objects under applicators (such as `then` and `allOf`) do not effect `additionalProperties`. Can you be a bit more specific about what you are expecting to happen, why, and what is actually happening please?

Comment: This isn't even valid JSON. Are you sure you are using JSON Schema?

Comment: @Relequestual I updated the example. What I'am trying to do is to return a validation error if amount is provided and also the transferType provided is not `ach`.

Comment: Thank you for updating the schema. Please can you provide example data with the current validation result and expected validation, explaining why. I think I understand what you're asking, but it's always best to check. We also need to know which version (or draft) of JSON Schema you're using. Your implementation should tell you which it defaults to and which it supports. You define which you want using `$schema`.

Comment: @Relequestual Thanks. I added what you asked.

Comment: "JSON Schema version: 0.2.3" Unfortunatly that would be the version of the library you are using, not the version of JSON Schema. JSON Schema has libraries in many languages. It would be great if you could let us know which library you are using AND what version of JSON Schema.

Comment: Thank you. I can see you're using ajv and that specific version supports draft-07 so that answers that question. While I review the question again, I feel you might benefit from reading about JSON Schema dialects: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/schema.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on your schema having `additionalProperties` set to false, it looks like you want only the properties you define to be allowed.

For draft-07 JSON Schema and prior, you have to add all the allowed fields to the `properties` object, even if you want some of them to be conditionally allowed or required. This is because `additionalProperties` only sees `properties` and `patternProperties` at the same object schema level. (It cannot "see through" applicator keywords like `if/then/else`.

The `properties` keyword only applies the schema values based on the matching keys in your instance data. If `amount` is listed in the `properties` but it's not found in the data, the subschema value won't be applied. This is why `required` is needed to specify which fields are... required.

In order to conditionally require or forbid keys in an object, AND prevent additional properties, you need to break up the validation of the values and the required/forbidden conditionality.

Your `if` subschema was correct, but I have modified the `then` and `else` schemas to only require or forbid `amount`. The `not` keyword inverts the subschema value result (It is not "not required", but more like `!` in boolean logic).

Here's a live demo of the below modified schema: https://jsonschema.dev/s/y7eq9

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "if": {
    "properties": { "transferType": { "const": "ach" } }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": ["amount"]
  },
  "else": {
    "not": {
      "required": ["amount"]
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "blockchainAddress": { "type": "string" },
    "callbackUrl": { "format": "uri", "type": "string" },
    "currency": { "type": "string" },
    "transferMethodId": { "format": "uuid", "type": "string" },
    "transferType": {
      "enum": [
        "ach",
        "internationalWire",
        "scUsdc",
        "wire"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    },
    "amount": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "blockchainAddress",
    "currency",
    "transferType"
  ]
}
```

If you were using JSON Schema draft-2019-09 or above, you could just replace `additionalProperties` with `uneavaluatedProperties`. You can test that on [THIS playground](https://json-schema.hyperjump.io/), but don't forget to change your `$schema` to the 2019-09 or newer dialect URI.